# Origine de l'expression « roulez jeunesse »

Tags: expressions, étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques

En recherchant l'origine de l'expression « roulez jeunesse » (que je suppose on pourrait plus précisément écrire « roulez, jeunesse »), j'ai trouvé çà et là des gens disant que cela viendrait des attractions foraines comme les autos-tamponneuses, où l'opérateur annonçait ainsi aux enfants le départ d'un nouveau tour (et donc qu'ils pouvaient *rouler*, après avoir attendu immobiles ce signal).

Est-ce bien cela l'origine ? Y a-t-il quelque chose d'un peu fiable sur lequel s'appuyer pour donner cette origine ?

Comment: Question intéressante, je l'ai entendue aussi dire aux jeunes conducteurs qui venaient d'avoir leur permis et qui partaient en ballade sans les parents.

Comment: De fait, il est certain que les forains, il y a quelques décennies, s'adressaient au public en l'appelant "jeunesse". Sur tous les stands générateurs de sensations fortes, on entendait les hauts-parleurs crier par exemple: "Et allons-y, jeunesse! Le Hully Gully vous attend!" (le Hully Gully était une de ces grandes roues dont on ressort avec la nausée...)

Answer (score 4):

Premièrement, on peut utiliser l'outil *ngram* de Google pour tenter [d'illustrer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Roulez%20jeunesse&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CRoulez%20jeunesse%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BRoulez%20jeunesse%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Broulez%20jeunesse%3B%2Cc0) quand l'expression se manifeste. Globalement, la représentation est faible dans l'[échantillon](http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/P/P12/P12-3029.pdf) utilisé par l'outil, mais une progression s'amorce à compter du milieu des années 1970(1976...).

Deuxièmement, au *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*(A. Rey, aux Ed. Le Robert), on indique que dès l'origine, le verbe *rouler* est basé sur *roue* qui lui est basé sur la racine latine [*rota*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DR%3Aentry%20group%3D32%3Aentry%3Drota) - essentiellement l'idée d'un disque sur un axe. D'autres langues se sont orientées vers la racine grecque qui s'intéresse davantage au mouvement(cercle). Au [*Trésor*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouler)(aussi [*DMF*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/rouler1?idf=dmfXgXrmXrjhc;str=0)) on fait état d'un parcours similaire avec plus ou moins de détails. Cependant, ces auteurs ne mentionnent en aucun cas l'expression envisagée ici. Rouler dans le contexte du véhicule c'est en soi du 16ième, avec l'ajout des sens rattachés au véhicule automobile au 20ième. Si l'on ne s'attarde uniquement qu'à des exemples d'expressions plus contemporaines, on voit se former au 19ième des trucs comme « rouler sa bosse », « rouler une cigarette », *faire rouler un carrosse* relié au train de vie, etc. Aussi intéressant [*rouleur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouleur) avec entre autres le marchand forain qui change trop souvent d'emplacement, où le cycliste doué pour le fond. Donc on retrouve des idées de mouvement, de déplacement à véhicule, de voyage, de légèreté, de remuer des choses, réfléchir, travailler, de prouesse etc; toutes des choses qui s'associent aisément à la jeunesse - qui roule.

Quant aux *autos tamponneuses*([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=autos%20tamponneuses&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cautos%20tamponneuses%3B%2Cc0)), le terme apparaît en 1945(REY) ou 1956([Trésor](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tamponneuse)) mais l'utilisation du mot *tamponneuse* en soi, à la toute fin du 19ième.<sup>1</sup> D'autre part, il faut peut-être aussi noter l'impact de l'engouement pour la course de [rallye](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rallye_automobile) automobile avec entres autres ces voitures des années [60](http://www.caradisiac.com/La-naissance-de-la-Coupe-Gordini-Roulez-jeunesse-page-50668.htm) et [70](http://www.webcarcenter.com/dossier/histoire_automobile/simca_rallye_2/histoire_rallye_2.html).

Généralement, on trouve aujourd'hui sur le web(recherche Google) plus de 150 000 entrées<sup>2</sup> avec l'expression, un peu partout dans la francophonie; on y retrouve aussi une entrée peu usitée, [« Tournez manèges et roulez jeunesse »](http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2004/07/09/164325-tournez-maneges-et-roulez-jeunesse.html). mais dont le contenu correspond exactement au contexte proposé.<sup>3</sup> Au cinéma, on trouve un film intitulé [*Roulez jeunesse!*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulez_jeunesse_!)(1993, J. Fanstren). Un magazine comme [Le Figaro](http://evene.lefigaro.fr/tout/roulez-jeunesse) contient aussi quelques entrées avec l'expression(roman, entrevue, etc.); aussi au [théâtre](http://luc-tartar.net/page.php?r=3&id=1).

---

**R**. D'après le *ngram*, l'expression est utilisée bien plus fréquemment depuis la fin des années 1970, et il est courant de la rencontrer sur le web aujourd'hui; mais, à mon avis,  ces observations ne permettent pas en soi d'identifier d'où proviendrait exactement l'expression, ni par conséquent d'affirmer si c'est directement relié ou non aux autos tamponneuses. Mais l'expression tient clairement la route; rarement avec la virgule cependant.

---

<sub>1. Un [site](http://www.lusseautoscooters.com/html/legend_history.html) semble indiquer que des preuves existaient à l'effet qu'une entreprise(Dodgem) qui fabriquait ce produit en livrait en France en 1927. Par ailleurs, comment passer sous silence ce [*document*](http://www.gatsbyonline.com/main.aspx?page=text&id=940&cat=auto) sur les autos tamponneuses routières!! Enfin, on peut [superposer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=autos%20tamponneuses%2Croulez%20jeunesse&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cautos%20tamponneuses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Croulez%20jeunesse%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BRoulez%20jeunesse%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Broulez%20jeunesse%3B%2Cc0) les courbes des ngrams de l'expression et celle des autos tamponneuses et spéculer. On peut *observer* que cette dernière connaît une période de croissance entre 1978 et 1987, mais dont le rythme n'est pas le même que pour l'expression recherchée.</sub>

<sub>2. Un bref échantillon: [BMX pour enfants en Suisse](http://nouvelles.ch/2013/05/roulez-jeunesse/), [Festival vélo-musique Lyon](http://www.roulez-jeunesse.com/festival/), [Skatepark île de la Réunion](http://www.femmemag.re/famille/roulez-jeunesse), [Vélo au Québec](http://www.geopleinair.com/destinations/Ptit-train-du-nord-roulez-jeunesse), [Stage conduite rurale en tracteur depuis 1972](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xirukw_roulez-jeunesse-en-tracteur-avec-10-de-conduite-rurale_animals), Blogs - [vélo élec.](http://www.mobilityurban.fr/blog/velo-electrique/roulez-jeunesse-en-velo-electrique.html) / [www.roulez-jeunesse.com](http://www.roulez-jeunesse.com/). L'expression couplée avec *France* retourne 75 000 résultats. Plein de trucs avec des roues, en particulier le vélo, et les références à la conduite de véhicules, mais aussi le voyage, ou d'autres utilisations [particulières](http://www.parismatch.com/Culture/Medias/Roulez-jeunesse-680414)(l'intellect ou le mouvement de la presse).</sub>

<sub>3. Je trouve que *tournez manèges et roulez jeunesse* ressemble d'une certaine manière à l'anglais [*rock-and-roll*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/rock-and-roll).</sub>

Comment: Réponse très documentée. Il faut ajouter la *roue de loterie*, j'ai souvent entendu cette formule magique lorsque le forain prenait son élan et lançait la roue pour qu'elle tourne le plus longtemps possible.

Comment: @cl-r Merci! Oui, _la roue de Fortune_, que j'aurais pu confondre avec un truc à la télé américaine, n'eût été de l'époque(1690)!